# Why do junks (ships) have such square noses?

Tags: technology, ships, shipbuilding

I saw a post on forum, and after some searching I can't seem to find a good answer as to why many junks have either flat fronts or square decks on the front (if they have pointed hulls). I have a few possible ideas:

- It's a structural feature for resisting stormy conditions in the S China Sea
- It's a cultural holdover from ancient times when these were river rafts
- It's designed to increase hold and deck size, allowing more cargo

I am assuming there is a relatively consistent reason, and am wondering if anyone more familiar with maritime technology or Asian history knows what it is.

Comment: I feel like this might be more in place over on [history.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/) as it's purely about the real world.

Comment: It might also be a possible example question for the new proposal [Sailing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/78852/sailing).

Comment: I agree this doesn't seem the place for this question.

Comment: Quite possibly, though I looked through History SE and didn't find much similar (it doesn't seem to focus on technology), and the original context in which it was asked was with regards to sailing in a fantasy context. It would be cool to have a Sailing SE though.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about a construction form which has no English term. In Germany we say "Kastenboot" (box - boat).

One example for this is the traditional Chinese [Junk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junk_%28ship%29).
There had been two main benefits of this construction form:

1. Easy to build. You don't need to bend wood, or not too much. Due bending wood is very sophisticating, in the past this was a massive benefit. It allows to build more ships in less time with less effort.
2. There's no or only a little radius in the hulk which means the ship can hold more cargo.

In modern day's these benefits can be archived with other techniques without the drawbacks (slow speed, ...) so it's not very common today.

Comment: I know of at least one common modern boat type which has a flat front: The [Optimist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimist_(dinghy)). However, it is designed for a special purpose: As a training sailboat for children.

Comment: Correct, but your comment must be seen as a sidenot, not a objection due it fits my answer. ("not very common" and "slow speed")

Comment: A comment is not always a complaint :)